# Do I Need To Preorder Infinite Warfare To Get Zombies?

Tags: call-of-duty-infinite-warfare, cod-infinite-warfare-zombies

I'm a bit confused, do I need to preorder IW to get Zombies? It sounded like that, so I did a little research and the CoD site says that pre-ordering gives you a few items in Zombies that you cannot get without preordering. So if I don't preorder I still get Zombies, right?

Also, I read that you only get Terminal if you preorder. Is that true?

Comment: They would give Terminal out for free like in AW and BO3 so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](https://charlieintel.com/2016/05/02/call-duty-infinite-warfare-co-op-mode-will-zombies/), it does not mention that you need to pre-order the game in order to get Zombies.  It would be in the games best interest not to limit content such as Zombies to pre-orders only, as it may result in loss of sales.

And from [another article](http://charlieintel.com/2016/07/21/preorder-infinite-warfare-get-access-terminal-bonus-map-mw2/) (from the same site) it says that *Terminal* is bonus content for pre-orders.  As the article states:

> This offer is available with the preorder of any edition of Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare and available on PlayStation 4, Xbox One, and PC. The offer is also available for digital preorders and for preorders at participating retailers.